# Extract html text files to text file

Tags: data-mining

I have a folder with lot of html files, I would like to extract only the text contained in the body of this html to a txt file, how can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over each file in the directory and use a command-line browser such as [lynx](http://lynx.invisible-island.net/) or [w3m](http://w3m.sourceforge.net/) to render the HTML to plaintext and save this into a text file.

Lynx example:

```
lynx -dump in.html > out.txt
```

w3m example:

```
w3m -dump in.html > out.txt
```